# Java SpringMVC How to access MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am following a Java [SpringMVC tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) about accessing the database. After setting up everything as instructed I am getting the following error after running the command `mvn spring-boot:run`

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
        - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
        - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.

[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at hello.Application.main(Application.java:15)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 34 more
```

The code from the tutorial page match the code in my project. Here are the settings in my `src/main/resources/application.properties` file.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java-accessing-db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

I am very new to the SpringMVC framework and Java. So I don't know what is causing the problem. I think my driver settings are not correct or I am missing a dependincy.

Comment: Do you have installed mysql server?

Comment: Yes, I MySQL server installed. I am running this on my local Windows machine which has XAMPP apache installed.

Comment: It seems like you lack a DAO.Which IDE do you use?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Java neon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add in properties file the dialect

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I don't know now if the problem is this.I think that you just missed to set a bean.So check DAO classes and Resources classes , maybe you forgot to @Autowired some of them.
Also keep in mind that Spring Data use repository check here [Working with SQL databases](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)
Check those 3 I believe you will find it , I will be happy to help.
Here is Spring-Elements tree you get in JEE Perspective       [image] If you could post this , it will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Thanks! That actually worked! Although I am not such whether it will always work, Why it worked and why spring.io does not include that in their tutorial. I am using Eclipse Java Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) Hopefully I will understand what a bean is and how to set it in the near future. I will also look at the @Autowired. Classes, Resources and Repositories I understand from other languages I have worked with,

Should I be using Eclipse JEE Neon for MVC projects?

Comment: I am using Eclipse too.I think that this is the best tool alongside intelliJ.I am also convinced that Spring tutorials are almost perfect and very straight forward.Maybe they mention this somewhere you haven't check.Happy to help though.Goodnight!